# windows tcp/ip settings per network

Tags: windows, networking, tcpip

In Windows 8.1 is there any *native* way to set network adapter settings per wireless network?

I need to have one network (essid) where I manually specify the ip-adresses and all others DHCP. 
DHCP is available on the network where I need to use manual settings however it doesn't assign the right address so "alternate configuration" is not an option.
It seems crazy that there is no way to get this done, but I couldn't find anything except "install program X".

Answer (score -1):

The only way a computer can know what network it's on is to have an IP address and gateway.  There is no way for the computer to know what network an adapter is plugged into oterwise.

Since the one network is giving a bad address, the only solution is to have a second NIC in your machine and make sure you always plug it into that adapter whenever you're on that network.  Or you can fix the DHCP problem (although I realize it may not be something within your control).

Comment: People are downvoting because my original post sounded rude.  So I reworded it.  But the point still stands.

Comment: Sorrry I should add my question is about wifi, I edited the question to reflect this. This is a software-issue, there is no fundamental problem. It just needs to be able to provide settings per essid, rather than per device. Any of my linux devices is able to do it, any macintosh can do it.